# Quando responder duas vezes

Tags: debate

Técnicamente é possivel que o mesmo autor responda mais de uma vez à mesma pergunta. Depois de [**esta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4423/como-remover-um-href-de-uma-tag-a-com-jquery-javascript) hoje, onde existem duas respostas do mesmo utilizador, surgiu-me a dúvida que pergunto aqui.

Qual é a opinião da comunidade acerca de:

> respostas multiplas **vs** melhorar reposta já existente

Quando é uma boa prática (?), e quando é uma má prática, dispersando informação e não contribuíndo para respostas completas (?).

Answer (score 13):

Faço minhas as palavras de outro usuário do SO, respondente [deste tópico](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125751/when-should-i-add-another-answer):

> If you can offer substantially different answers to the problem, that can be a case where multiple separate answers are appropriate, but each should be able to stand by its own merits, of course. Variations of the same theme belong in the same post, making more than one answer of them just adds noise.
>
> Even if you suggest two unrelated ways to solve a problem, if they are short enough, they should usually be (separate) parts of one post, since more posts clutter the page. Unless they don't fit together. For example if one of them uses very controversial techniques, having them in the same post would make voting difficult. It would force people to a) upvote content they disapprove of, b) not upvote content they strongly approve of, c) downvote content they approve of, d) not downvote content they strongly disapprove of. Seems undesirable.

*"Se você pode oferecer duas respostas bastante distintas a um problema, pode ser o caso onde seja conveniente ter múltiplas respostas, mas cada uma deve ter seus próprios méritos. **Variações de um mesmo tema devem ficar em um só post**, pois separá-las em respostas diferentes apenas causa bagunça.*

*Mesmo que você sugira duas formas diferentes de se resolver um problema, se as propostas forem curtas, você deve fazê-las de forma separada em um único post, para não poluir a página. A menos que as respostas realmente não se encaixem juntas. Por exemplo, se você utilizar técnicas bastante distintas e sem intersecção, usá-las em um mesmo post dificulta a votação. Isso forçaria as pessoas a a) votarem positivamente em conteúdo com o qual não concordam, b) não votar positivamente em conteúdo com o qual concordam, c) votar negativamente em respostas com as quais concordam ou d), não votar negativamente em conteúdo com o qual não concordam. Isso parece indesejável."*

Se você oferece duas respostas suficientemente distintas, e a acreditar que ambas resolvem o problema, eu posso votar positivamente em uma resposta e negativamente em outra. Mas se forem duas formas diferentes de expressar a mesma ideia, acho necessário sinalizar ambas as respostas.

No caso da pergunta mencionada, acredito que parece ser o caso de soluções realmente distintas. Ênfase em *parece*. Uma das respostas está mais próxima do formato de um comentário do que de uma resposta propriamente dita.