# Duas respostas para esta pergunta, devo fazer?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, respostas

Para [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/310945/64969) em específico, tenho duas abordagens consideravelmente distintas para resposta:

- usando memoização e recursão
- usando pré-processamento através do crivo de Eratóstenes

Porém, elas tem uma pequena interseção na propriedade matemática logo na introdução da resolução.

Assim sendo, devo fazer as duas respostas? Ou apenas uma que contempla ambas as estratégias?

Minha dúvida não senti sanada ao [ler isto daqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/782/64969). Há a interseção, porém não sei se grande o suficiente para por em um canto só.

---

Conforme sugestão do @Maniero, já escrevi uma das respostas que eu desejava: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/310975/64969

A outra porei aqui em sequência, e dependendo da recepção, farei dela uma nova resposta ou uma edição na resposta original.

### A segunda resposta

Podemos atacar a questão com um pouco mais de matemática, para então podermos usar outros conceitos de programação. Nesta aqui, vamos aproveitar o fato de que é possível (e eficiente) pré-computar os primos. Um pouco de pré-processamento em um conjunto inicial pode tornar muito mais rápida uma computação futura, ainda mais quando ela é feita repetidas vezes.

> Normalmente, em questões de programação competitiva, o programa roda uma única vez e é testado contra uma gama de entradas possíveis. Um exemplo disso é o modelo da Maratona de Programação ACM. A OBI, na minha lembrança, já foi assim também, porém por um tempo ela mudou a abordagem para que cada execução do programa seja um por entrada; então, assim, tem-se que o programa seria executado 15 vezes se fossem 15 casos de testes.

Para fazer esse pré-processamento, vou usar um algoritmo conhecido desde a época dos antigos gregos: [o crivo de Eratóstenes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231668/64969).

Ele começa com uma lista booleana. A priori, todo número tem o potencial de ser primo, porém, ao se achar um número primo de verdade, todos os múltiplos dele devem ser marcados como não-primo. Você pode otimizar a execução dele para diminuir a memória pela metade, a dispêndio de um pouco a mais de cálculo (mais umas 3, 4 operações aritméticas por acesso a posição no vetor). Você também pode otimizar para, para cada primo encontrado, fazer apenas `o(n/p - p)` operações de "anulação de potencial de primo". Veja mais detalhes do algoritmo [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231668/64969).

Não me recordo o tempo de execução do crivo, mas ela é algo maior que linear e menor do que quadrática. E tem a vantagem de só se executar uma única vez e se pode guardar os resultados para sempre.

O "retorno" dessa função é uma lista com os primos existentes, e o argumento é ou o número de primos desejado ([resposta do Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231668/64969)) ou o tamanho máximo do maior primo. Eu acho que para o seu caso devemos passar `10000` (dez mil) que devemos ter alguma margem de segurança. Eu não posso afirmar com certeza, você não pôs as restrições de entrada para o seu problema.

Vamos assumir que a variável preenchida com os primos obtidos pelo crivo de Eratóstenes se chame `primos`, e a quantidade total de primos achada se chame `qnt_primos`. Se se deseja somar todos os primos no intervalo fechado `[numI, numF]`, então só fazer o seguinte:

```
int i;
int soma = 0;
int numero_iterado;

// ... faz os primos, faz as leituras necessárias

for (i = 0; i < qnt_primos; i++) {
  numero_iterado = primos[i];

  if (numero_iterado < numI) {
    continue; // volte para o começo do laço, ainda nem cheguei no mínimo 
  } else if (numero_iterado > numF) {
    break; // achei um primo que vai além do valor final, posso parar
  }
  soma += numero_iterado; // primo no intervalo, deve somar
}
printf("%d", soma);
```

Se quiser, é ainda fácil considerar um algoritmo de busca binária para achar o índice `j` do menor primo disponível, que é `primos[j] <= numI`.

Comment: Eu sempre opto por uma unica resposta divida com uma linha horizontal `----` (`<hr>`), mas é um "gosto pessoal meu"

Comment: Pq seu título tá estilo Yoda? Quase _"corrigi"_ para `"o que devo fazer?"`

Comment: @Math escrevi conforme o pensamento fluiu xD Culpa minha não é por em inversões pensar

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , coloquei a candidata à segunda resposta no texto da pergunta. Crê ainda que deve ser algo separado por uma barra horizontal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na minha curta experiência no site vi pouquíssimos casos em que o mesmo autor possuía duas abordagens para o mesmo problema, então acho que não é necessário discutir o que vale ou não a pena fazer. Faça aquilo que for mais simples para você, desde que coloque as duas abordagens.

Eu *precisei* apenas uma vez, nesta pergunta: [GroupBy em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182050/5878). Também caberia ou duas respostas distintas ou na mesma, porém, como achei que estava estendendo muito para uma resposta e poderia ficar confuso para o leitor absorver ambos os conteúdos sem dificuldade, optei por separá-las.

Acredito que seu caso seja o mesmo. Se a intersecção entre elas é apenas a introdução conceitual, coloque este trecho em uma das respostas e na outra apenas cite-a. Não vejo porque duplicar o conteúdo, assim como vejo/imagino que recursão e o crivo são assuntos bastante extensos e seriam melhor expostos em respostas diferentes.

Answer (score 5):

Duas respostas parecem melhor, mas sempre só dá para ter certeza depois de ver a resposta :D

Comment: Coloquei a sugestão de outra resposta no corpo desta pergunta do meta.