# Formato dos links: [descrição](url) ou [1]... [2]... [3]... ou...?

Tags: debate, hyperlinks

Qual a recomendação com relação ao formato dos links incluídos no conteúdo de perguntas e respostas?

Tudo bem linkar só com:

```
[descrição](url)
```

ou é sempre recomendado usar:

```
[1]...
[2]...
[3]...
```

ou ainda usar:

```
[Link mais significativo]...
```

?

Comment: O que você preferir. Eu uso mais o de cima (poucos links para gerenciar). Quando uso o de baixo, uso aliases mais significativos do que números

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Usar a segunda forma com aliases mais significativos é o que eu considero ideal. Mas dá tanto trabalho que praticamente não uso

Comment: Aliás, essa é uma crítica que eu tenho ao Markdown, apesar de gostar do conceito: dá muitas formas de fazer a mesma coisa, e acho que isso acaba complicando os parsers e "promovendo" a inconsistência. No caso dos links eu até não mudaria, mas nas minhas coisas eu adoto um outro formato que não aceita HTML de forma alguma, e elimino redundâncias (por exemplo, `*negrito*` e `_italico_`, não vejo sentido em usar `**` e o pior, o `__` ter o mesmo sentido). Algumas coisas até fazem sentido ter mais de um formato, mas mesmo assim, poderiam ser normalizadas.

Comment: Prefiro, a segunda para organizar melhor, se precisar atualizar os links, acaso o endereço mude e ainda pode reaproveitar os links em mais de um lugar do corpo da postagem.

Comment: Para mim a maior diferença é que com  `[desc][1]` você consegue referenciar o mesmo link múltiplas vezes caso queira, escrevendo o url apenas uma vez, assim como também fica com uma lista de links usados no fim da pergunta/resposta, quase como se fosse um índice.

Comment: @Isac sim, como eu citei, reaproveitar e a vantagem do indice, como disse também, organizar e se precisar corrigir os links eles estarão fáceis em um lugar só

Comment: Estou editando uma pergunta aqui em que precisei repetir o link duas vezes. Particularmente eu não vejo isso acontecendo com frequência, por isso que acaba que eu amplamente ignoro a pós-referência. Há casos também em que o infeliz do criador do link pôs parênteses na URL, então eu não conheço outra alternativa a não ser a pós-referência para resolver isso. Ah, tem no texto uma pós-referência numérica incremental porque eu esqueci o link na hora da escrita (nota: uso mais o app) e é mais fácil inserir através da interface do app, sendo que aí ele cria **sempre** pós-referência incremental

Comment: Pronto, feita a publicação que mistura os 3 jeitos de se usar links: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7155/64969

Comment: Acabo usando a segunda pois é a forma que a interface de pergunta/resposta do SO coloca os links :). Acho legal também porque fica mais fácil de ler o texto quando está editando ele, pois você não perde a atenção lendo longos links no meio do texto.